# How to take substring from input file as an argument to a program to be executed in GNU-parallel?

Tags: gnu-parallel

I am trying to execute a program (say, `biotool`) using GNU-parallel which takes 3 arguments, `i`, `o` and `a` :

- the input files (`i`)
- output file name to be written in (`o`)
- an argument which takes a sub string from the input file name (`a`)

for example, say i have 10 text files like this

```
1_a_test.txt
2_b_test.txt
3_c_test.txt
...
10_j_test.txt
```

I want to run my tool (say biotool) on all the 10 text files. I tried this

`parallel biotool -i {} -o {.}.out -a {} ::: *.txt`

I want to pass the charachter/letter/whatever before the first underscore from the input text file name as an argument to `-a` option like this (dry run):

```
parallel biotool -i 1_a_test.txt -o 1_a_test.out -a 1 ::: *.txt`
parallel biotool -i 2_b_test.txt -o 2_b_test.out -a 2 ::: *.txt`
parallel biotool -i 3_c_test.txt -o 3_c_test.out -a 3 ::: *.txt`
...
```

`{}` supplies the complete file name to `-a` but I only want the sub string before the first underscore to be supplied to `-a`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest, but harder to read is this:

```
parallel --dry-run biotool -i {} -o {.}.out -a '{= s/_.*// =}'  ::: *test.txt
```

---

Alternatively, you can make a `bash` function that uses `bash` *Parameter Substitution* to extract the part before the underscore. Then export that to make it known to **GNU Parallel**

```
#!/bin/bash

doit(){
  i=$1
  o=$2
  # Use internal bash parameter substitution to extract whatever precedes "_" 
  # See https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html
  a=${i/_*/}
  echo biotool -i "$i" -o "$o" -a "$a"
}

export -f doit

parallel doit {} {.}.out ::: *test.txt
```

**Sample Output**

```
biotool -i 10_j_test.txt -o 10_j_test.out -a 10
biotool -i 1_a_test.txt -o 1_a_test.out -a 1
biotool -i 2_b_test.txt -o 2_b_test.out -a 2
```

Comment: Use `--plus` and `{%string}`: `parallel --plus --dry-run biotool -i {} -o {.}.out -a {%.._test.txt}  ::: *test.txt`

Comment: @Mark Setchell  can you explain the `'{= s/_.*// =}'` part? And consequently how would we extract 'a' 'b' and 'c' instead of 1,2,3 in the example?

Comment: @user2635088 Just ask anothef question - they are free and any one if 15 million programmers may answer rather than just me, so you'll probably do much better that way.